# Unable to set SDK path or download that in Android Studio 3.6?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I installed Android Studio 3.6 on Windows 10 from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio) downloaded
but when check Android SDK manager ( tools>SDK manager ) on Android Studio show me "target folder is neither empty nor does it point to an existing SDK installation" error and empty path for SDK.
I download some android SDK. but don't work all of them. Android Studio show me SDK is installed and not permit me checked check box of download/update SDK

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe your SDK is saved in another folder.

Comment: when change the directory to correct folder, have this error "target folder is neither empty nor does it point to an existing SDK installation".

Comment: Please give me your email address or Whatsapp number, I will send SDK for you

Comment: email: ehsan69h@yahoo.com. tnx

Comment: You may download from this site: https://novindevelopers.com/download-sdk/

Comment: Unfortunately, this SDK don't work for me, like previous version

Comment: What is your version of AS? Go to 3.6.2 please

Comment: in version 3.6.2

Comment: Hi, excuse me not to sending SDK, it has about 4 Gig volume. Your version of AS is correct and according to bottom image you have attached, SDK is installed. I don;t know what is problem when you click next button.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are pointing to zip file that SDK folder is in it. You should directly point to SDK folder. If it is in a zip file, first extract it. SDK folder has files similar to this:

[image]

Comment: i was downloaded this from (https://developer.android.com/studio). and just contain "tools" folder. you suggest where can i download SDK?

Comment: All the folders you see in my image aren't necessary. The best recommendation is that you get SDK from somebody who uses that for his system. When you don't specify any folder, AS will dowmload from the web itself by your click.@ehsanHB

Comment: See this page for more explanation@ehsanHB    https://www.androidcentral.com/installing-android-sdk-windows-mac-and-linux-tutorial

Comment: i see that link. but i have problem on this section of guideline ("Open the bin folder in the extracted download and find the sdkmanager executable file. It may look like a terminal or shell command but it will open a GUI as long as you have Java installed correctly."). this file haven't any reaction on my PC.

Comment: Do you have bin folder?@ehsanHB

Comment: i execute that. show a bash window in 1 sec and close that. just it

Comment: this result of java -version command.
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)

Comment: "In the SDK manager you'll choose to install Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-Tools. If you're using Windows you'll also want to install the Google USB Driver" You have done this@ehsanHB

Comment: but SDK manager don't work for me. i set a screenshot on question

Comment: Why don't you click Next?@ehsanHB

Comment: because this directory is selected not exist on my PC and when change to correct location, this error show tome "target folder is neither empty nor does it point to an existing SDK installation"