# Android SDK not found - but the folder exists

Tags: android

This is the result of flutter doctor :

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [√]
>   Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows
>   [Version 10.0.15063], locale en-US) [X] Android toolchain - develop
>   for Android devices
>       X ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Bert\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
>         but Android SDK not found at this location. [√] Android Studio (version 3.6) [!] Connected device
>       ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61046256/unable-to-set-sdk-path-or-download-that-in-android-studio-3-6/61056154#61056154

Comment: This issue doesn't provide any information that would allow to diagnose.
At first please add the output of `flutter doctor -v`

Answer (score 0):

Sigh...fixed it by reinstalled everything...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
flutter config --android_sdk="$HOME/Android/Sdk"
```

- Make sure that you point to the actual directory where the sdk is installed on your machine (In my case it is installed at $HOME/Android/Sdk)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just check that the platform is also installed, because I found it missing. I had to (re)install it:

[image: Screenshot]